# Why can't I insert the data to db in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel

I want to insert data to `db` using only something like `DB::insert`.
So, I have this line of code:

```php
DB::insert("INSERT INTO `users` (`vk_id`, `name`, `email`) VALUES ($user->id, $user->name, $user->email)");
```

I do use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

But I have an error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'DB' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

What's the cause of this error?

**The whole file code**

```php
<?php

namespace SocialiteProviders\VKontakte;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException;
use SocialiteProviders\Manager\OAuth2\AbstractProvider;
use SocialiteProviders\Manager\OAuth2\User;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Provider extends AbstractProvider
{
    protected $fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'screen_name', 'photo_200'];

    /**
     * Unique Provider Identifier.
     */
    const IDENTIFIER = 'VKONTAKTE';

     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $stateless = true;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $scopes = ['email'];

    /**
     * Last API version.
     */
    const VERSION = '5.92';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getAuthUrl($state)
    {
        return $this->buildAuthUrlFromBase(
            'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize', $state
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenUrl()
    {
        return 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
        $from_token = [];
        if (is_array($token)) {
            $from_token["email"] = isset($token["email"]) ? $token["email"] : null;

            $token = $token["access_token"];
        }

        $params = http_build_query([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'fields'       => implode(',', $this->fields),
            'lang'     => $this->getConfig('lang', 'en'),
            'v'            => self::VERSION,
        ]);

        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?' . $params);

        $contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        $response = json_decode($contents, true);

        if (!is_array($response) || !isset($response['response'][0])) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Invalid JSON response from VK: %s',
                $contents
            ));
        }

        return array_merge($from_token, $response['response'][0]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function user() {
        if ($this->hasInvalidState()) {
            throw new InvalidStateException;
        }

        $response = $this->getAccessTokenResponse($this->getCode());

        $user = $this->mapUserToObject($this->getUserByToken($response));

        $this->credentialsResponseBody = $response;

        if ($user instanceof User) {
            $user->setAccessTokenResponseBody($this->credentialsResponseBody);
        }

        return $user->setToken($this->parseAccessToken($response))
            ->setExpiresIn($this->parseExpiresIn($response));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
            'id'       => Arr::get($user, 'id'),
            'nickname' => Arr::get($user, 'screen_name'),
            'name'     => trim(Arr::get($user, 'first_name').' '.Arr::get($user, 'last_name')),
            'email'    => Arr::get($user, 'email'),
            'avatar'   => Arr::get($user, 'photo_200'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getTokenFields($code)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getTokenFields($code), [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Set the user fields to request from Vkontakte.
     *
     * @param array $fields
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function fields(array $fields)
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function additionalConfigKeys()
    {
        return ['lang'];
    }

    DB::insert('insert into users (vk_id, name, email) values (?, ?, ?)', [
        $user->id, $user->name, $user->email
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Your error seems to suggest that you have a syntax problem before your `DB:insert` line (unexpected `DB`, meaning it's expecting something else, like a `;`, or `}`, etc.) Post a bit more of your code.

Comment: check the code above that line maybe you forgot to put semi colon or closing brace.

Comment: You need to show us more of the code *around* the DB call.

Comment: There you go. That's the file I have: https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/VKontakte/blob/master/Provider.php

Comment: where is the db insert there

Comment: nowhere. Just imagine that there is a sting, I gave you before

Comment: @slower. No, show us the actual code where you have the DB call. Your issue is almost certainly the line or two *before* the DB call not being terminated correctly.

Comment: Ok, wait a sec.

Comment: VS code does't show any errors, so I am sure code before is correct

Comment: @slower. Thank you for providing your code. You can't have your DB::insert call directly in the class like that. You need to have it inside a function. If you want something to run every time the class is instantiated, put it in the constructor function.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, you can not put your statements directly in the class construction, instead you have to put it inside a function or the constructor of the class.

But also note that:

> Raw statements will be injected into the query as strings, so you
>   should be extremely careful to not create SQL injection
>   vulnerabilities.

So it's better to use this statement instead, because parameter binding provides protection against SQL injection.:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::insert('insert into users (vk_id, name, email) values (?, ?, ?)', [
    $user->id, $user->name, $user->email
]);
```

Or simply:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::table('users')->insert([
    'vk_id' => $user->id,
    'email' => $user->email,
    'name' => $user->name
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working, but thanks for your try

Comment: @slower. Don't ignore Hafez's point about SQL injection. It's important, and he's showed how to make your DB call safe and secure. You should implement that change along with fixing your syntax error.

Comment: I do tried his code, but the error is still the same.

Comment: @slower. as others said too, it's because you have syntax error before this line of code.